# Rally SOAPUI POST Queries

Tags: rally, ca

I'm trying to a create a Rally project in `SOAPUI` with POST queries, I'm using GET query for authorization and than try to send a request with the POST query, with the key I get in authorization query, but when I send the request I get an error

> "Not authorized to preform action: Invalid key".

(basically I'm trying to do the same thing I'm doing in Postman)

what am I doing wrong? 
How can use the POST queries correctly in `SOAPUI`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSRF token you need to supply for any POST/PUT/DELETE requests.  All of the built-in toolkits we have for WSAPI handle it automatically.  Basically you need to make a request to `/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize` and include your basic auth headers.  That response will contain the token that you can then include in any requests using the key query string parameter.

It's all documented here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/authentication.jsp